# sharepoint custom action Dynamic image icon

Tags: master-page, custom-actions, http-module, file-icons, rendering-template

I must build a custom Action for  sp2010 but its image must be according to some sharepoint values. 
For example: Alerts are ON or OFF for a SpList, then  icon is RED or GREEN. 
This check should be made by javascript.

Is there any way to do this set this Custom action Dynamically on page Request?

Comment: can you please explain your question properly with some example?

Comment: suppose you  have button control on your Ribbon, that shows you if alerts are active for that List. If Alerts are enabled, you will see the backgroud color green, otherwise coler red. How can my cautom action do this check every time i reload the page?